# How to use a JSON object created in code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

In Info.aspx.cs i get a compressed file from the WebService. After decoding the content i have an xml File. Using `XmlToJSON` and `JavaScriptSerializer` the result is a JSON object. How can i use this object in Info.aspx?

Comment: What do you want to do with the object in the ASPX? Use it in some JavaScript? Print out some text from its props?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your json is n below format

```
 var A={
    propertyOne: "propertyOne",
    propertyTwo: "propertyTwo"
 }
```

Use as below:

```
A.propertyOne
A.propertyTwo
```

Comment: How does Info.aspx knows that i have ´Var A´ in Info.aspx.cs

Comment: This is a just example. you can use as your

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var returnValue = new Object();
        returnValue.entityfirst = $("#entityfirst ").val();
        returnValue.entitysecond = $("#entitysecond ").val();
        returnValue.entitythird = $("#entitythird").val();

var request = $.ajax({
                    url: ..., //access method url
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(returnValue),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In you aspx page you have to use javascript if you do a dynamic load.

for example you call and recieve like this (jQuery) :

```
$.ajax({
                url: "myUrlPageForCallJsonService",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "yourParamsForGettingJson"
                    dataType: 'json',
                    complete: function (results) { console.log('complete'); },
                    success: function (data) { //You logic in the success function
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            console.log("success");
                            _html += '<li>'+ data[i].Param1 + '</li>';
                        }

                        _html += '</ul>';
                        $('#renderbody').html(_html);
                    },
                    fail: function (data) { console.log("fail"); }
                });
```

Hope that's help